# ngx-swiper-wrapper slider takes the focus of screen right away

Tags: javascript, angular, slider, carousel, swiper.js

I am using ngx-swiper-wrapper in my angular application on the first page. and I am facing with buggy scenario on page load which user tries to scroll down, however s/he will end up changing slides. 
Obviously slider/swiper/carousel is getting the focus of mouse instantly which is not a ideal behavior.

The following is my selected code inside the home component

```
import {
        SwiperComponent,
        SwiperConfigInterface,
        SwiperDirective,
} from 'ngx-swiper-wrapper';

export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {
   slideIndex: number = 0;
   public config: SwiperConfigInterface = {
          a11y: true,
          direction: 'horizontal',
          slidesPerView: 1,
          keyboard: true,
          mousewheel: true,
          scrollbar: false,
          navigation: true,
          pagination: false
   };

   @ViewChild(SwiperComponent, { static: false }) componentRef?: SwiperComponent;
   @ViewChild(SwiperDirective, { static: false }) directiveRef?: SwiperDirective;

   constructor(private zone: NgZone) { }

  ngOnInit() {
      this.runTimer();
  }

    runTimer() {
                this.zone.runOutsideAngular(() => {
                        setInterval(() => {
                                          if (this.slideIndex <= 2) {
                                                         this.slideIndex++;
                                                         this.directiveRef.setIndex(this.slideIndex);
                                          } else {
                                               this.slideIndex = 0;
                                               this.directiveRef.setIndex(this.slideIndex);
                                          }
                                       }, 5000);
                                   });
              }

}
```

How can I change the configuration to avoid it?

Answer (score 0):

Set mousewheel to false and change it to true on hover